# Batch Intersect Not Working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, batch, error-000210, intersect

I'm trying to run a batch job for the Intersect(Analysis) tool in ArcMap 10.3, but when I do for 20 intersects, it brings back this error:

> **ERROR 000210: Cannot create output.**

However, when I do an individual intersect on the same shapefiles, it works perfectly fine.

I have tried restarting my session but get the same message, so is there I'm not aware of about this error?

Comment: Are you doing this in batch by using the batch grid, ModelBuilder, ArcPy, or something else?

Comment: I just did it in a batch grid. Does it make a difference if my shapefiles are in a geodatabase or just a folder?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your batch grid prior to execution?

Comment: Try running it as a batch with just 2 intersects.  If it doesn't spit out the same error, then we'll know it has to do with the number of times the operation is being run, rather than the batch execution itself.